# ¿Cual es la diferencias entre JWT y Oauth 2.0 para la autentificacion de peticiones a un Api REST?

Tags: webservice, jwt, oauth2

Quiero implementar la autentificacion de las peticiones a mi API REST que va a ser consumida desde una aplicación móvil.
Aun no me decido por JWT o Oauth 2.0, cual me recomiendan.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso yo utilizo Oauth 2.0 si quiero que el cliente se autentifique mediante un tercero (intermediario) como Facebook, Paypal, Google+... Si únicamente quieres que se identifiquen mediante el registro en tu web, veo menos complejo implementar JWT.

La diferencia, es que normalmente Oauth se piden las credenciales a un servidor de identificación (normalmente un tercero) y requiere más pasos para obtener el token que con JWT, también pueden tener los tokens un cuerpo diferente con distinta información y cifrado, en este aspecto JWT yo creo que es más personalizable.